# Как скрыть навигацию при уменьшении экрана и оставить иконки?

Tags: css, media-queries

Home
 Delivery

При уменьшении размера экрана как можно убрать..home и delivery и оставить только иконки fa fa-home ?

Display: none пробовала удаляет вместе с иконками

Comment: <nav class="nav">                                                                                                                                            <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>                                              <a href="index1.html"><i class="fa fa-motorcycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delivery</a>

Comment: Сделайте два блока с навигацией и через display: none прячьте один из них для разной ширины вьюпорта.

Comment: Спасибо большое